# Trackballcontrols or Orbitcontrols?

Tags: three.js

First please excuse my bad english writing and please note that I am a Javascript NOOB!

I am currently developing a website for a client where I am presenting different kind of "wood cut" in webgl but I am unable to get the desired look an feel...

My goal is to make the viewer look and react like what we can see at Sketchfab.
http://sketchfab.com/show/9f7e1e088f0943b697e809f224f8c76d

The rotation is limited to a certain angle and the model always stay in the right position... With Trackballcontrols the model rotate all the way and its a mess. I have tried to change the quaternion as follow:

**from:
_this.object.up.applyQuaternion( quaternion );**

**to:
_this.object.up.applyQuaternion( new THREE.Vector4(0,0,0,1) );**

but it behave weird when I reach a certain angle, the model become jumpy...

Then I tried with Orbitcontrols but it seems that there is no dynamicDamping because the controls are really "dry". I prefer a smoother effect...

**1-** So is there a way to use Orbitcontrols and get the dynamicDamping to work?

**2-** Is it possible to modify Trackballcontrols to get the desired result?

an example of my models are here:
http://www.boissilvac.ca/new/nosproduits/patron19

Thank you for your time

Comment: The flipping at certain angles are properly caused by a singularity in your view matrix or more specific to prevent the matrix from becoming singular. You'll need to handle/restrict those extreme degrees of rotations somehow to avoid the flipping.

Comment: So you mean that the only way for me would be to restrict rotations over a certain angle? If so, do you know where I should look to get the information on how to do this in Trackballcontrols.js?

Comment: 1. Yes, but you have to modify the code. 2. Yes, but you have to completely rewrite it. In your case, use OrbitControls.

Comment: Ok Thank You WestLangley, can you point me in the right direction to find info on how to modify Orbitcontrols to get smoother controls?

Comment: Maybe some logic as in http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_shapes could be incorporated.

Comment: Ok Thanks Ill have a look